# How to filter rows from dataframe depending on contents of other rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe defined as

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo', '', '', 'foo', 'quux', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz'],
              'col2': ['', 'gb', '', 'de', 'gb', '', 'es', 'es'],
              'col3': [123, float("NaN"), 456, 723, 456, 123, 123, 721],
              'col4': ['', '', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', '', 'val4', 'val5'],
              'value': [1, 1, .4, .5, .3, 1, .5, .4]})
```

Which looks like

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | foo |  | 123.0 |  | 1.0 |
| 1 |  | gb | NaN |  | 1.0 |
| 2 |  |  | 456.0 | val1 | 0.4 |
| 3 | foo | de | 723.0 | val2 | 0.5 |
| 4 | quux | gb | 456.0 | val3 | 0.3 |
| 5 | baz |  | 123 |  | 1 |
| 6 | baz | es | 123 | val4 | .5 |
| 7 | baz | es | 721 | val5 | 0.4 |

I would like to filter this table and remove any rows where the value is equal to 1.0, but also any rows that have the same values in the populated columns as the value==1.0 rows. So in the above table, we would remove rows 0, 1, and 5 since the value==1.0, and also remove row 3 because col1=='foo' and row 4 because col2=='gb', and row 6 because col1='baz' AND col3=123. Rows 2 and 7 should be retained.

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 |  |  | 456.0 | val1 | 0.4 |
| 3 | foo | de | 723.0 | val2 | 0.5 |
| 7 | baz | es | 721 | val5 | 0.4 |

What's the best way to do this? I could find all the rows where the value==1.0 and then iterate through them and filter out all the rows from the table that have the same values in the set columns, but iterating through dataframe rows isn't ideal. I also thought of doing a merge, but I'm also not sure how to tell a merge to ignore columns where there is no value set.

Comment: Are you looking to filter rows if 'foo' appears in any column? Or is it just 'col1', 'col2'?

Comment: if 'foo' appears in 'col1' and if 'gb' appears in 'col2'.

Comment: Only two particular strings 'foo' , 'gb' or any string that is in row containing 1.0?

Comment: Any string that is in a row containing 1.0. And any combination of columns. So if there is also a row where col1 = 'something' and col2 = 'else' and value = 1.0, I'd want to filter any rows where col1 = 'something' AND col2 = 'else', regardless of values in col3 and col4.

Comment: Added a couple more data points to the table to clarify this point.

Comment: Why row 7 is not removed although col1='baz'?

Comment: Because the row where col1='baz' also has col3=123. Row 7 doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Let us do

```
cond = df.loc[df.value==1,]
filter = df[~(df.col1.isin(cond.col1[cond.col1!=''])|df.col2.isin(cond.col2[cond.col2!='']))]
filter
Out[443]: 
  col1 col2   col3  col4  value
2            456.0  val1    0.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I added some more information to the question which I think was insufficiently specified before.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest doing a treatment per-columns.

```
# First get rows where value is 1
temp = df.query('value == 1')

# Then, collect all unique values from the columns of interest.
vals1, vals2 = temp.col1[temp.col1.ne('')].unique(), temp.col2[temp.col2.ne('')].unique()

# Finally, filter.
df.loc[~(np.isin(df.col1, vals1) | np.isin(df.col2, vals2))]
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work since any columns, or combinations of columns, could be used for filtering. What matters is whether the value in a row == 1. If it is, then all the set values in the columns in that row are indicators for filtering. I added some clarifying information about this in the question.

Comment: @Catherine The logic I present is for 2 columns, but is easily extended for N columns. Have you thought of creating a for-loop over the columns and keeping the logic? I believe this should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
s = set(filter(lambda x:len(str(x)) > 0, 
           np.ravel(df.loc[df['value'].eq(1.0)].fillna('')[['col1', 'col2']].values)))
df = df[~(df['col1'].isin(s) | df['col2'].isin(s))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with binary slicing with `numpy` as this is straight forward and (for me) most readable:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo', '', '', 'foo', 'quux'],
                'col2': ['', 'gb', '', 'de', 'gb'],
                'col3': [123, float("NaN"), 456, 723, 456],
                'col4': ['', '', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
                'value': [1, 1, .4, .5, .3]})

target = pd.Series({'value': 1.0, 'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'gb'})

# determine which rows meet the target specifications
lg = np.all(df[target.index] == target, axis=1)

# using slicing
df = df[~lg]
# using drop
df.drop(lg[lg].index)
```

the good thing about this is that your are flexible with regard how to proceed with the logical vector `lg` or the interesting indices `lg[lg].index` =)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
eq1 = df[df['value'].eq(1)].replace('', float("NaN"))

df[~df.apply(lambda x: (eq1 == x).any(axis=None), axis=1)]
```